# Area of $(x-p)^2+(y-q)^2=r^2$ using double integrals?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, indefinite-integrals

How to calculate area of circle $(x-p)^2+(y-q)^2=r^2$ using double integrals?

I am assuming that area should be equal to area of circle $x^2+y^2=r^2$ because $p$ and $q$ doesn't affect the dimensions of circle just Its position.

So if we calculate double integral over region $x^2+y^2=r^2$, using polar coordinates, we get:

$
\int_0^{2\pi} d\phi \int_0^r \rho d\rho = r^2\pi
$

So is It same for equation $(x-p)^2+(y-q)^2=r^2$ ?

I have same question for volume of sphere.Using triple integrals to calculate Its volume, do we get different results for 
$x^2+y^2+z^2<=1$ and $x^2+(y-1)^2+(z-2)^2 <= 1$ ?

Comment: It's the same. Your question is equivalent to "is the volume of a sphere the same if we move it somewhere else?"

Comment: You can do the change of variables : $u=x-p,\,v=y-q$, with $dudv=dxdy$, to transform the problem to the problem of calculation of the area of a circle centred at the origin.

Comment: Maybe of interest https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/854671/double-integral-calculating-without-translating-a-circle-to-0-0

Answer (score 1):

You mean this integral?
$$
\int_{p-r}^{p+r} \left(\int_{q-\sqrt{r^2-(x-p)^2}}^{q+\sqrt{r^2-(x-p)^2}}  \,dy \right)\,dx
$$